# Post complex object to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Recently trying to upgrade my code to asp.net core from mvc5
I am trying to post a complex object from razor view to my controller but nothing is posted. What am I suppose to put in my view for this to work?

My Matchresult VM is always empty when posting this.
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SetResults[i].Team1Result) in a for loop is this correct?
My models and viewmodels

```
 public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Matchdate { get; set; }
    public string MatchNote { get; set; }
    public int RoundID { get; set; }
    public virtual Round MatchBelongsToRound { get; set; }


    public int? Team1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team1 { get; set; }


    public int? Team2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team2 { get; set; }

    public int? WinningTeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team WinningTeam { get; set; }
    public int? DivisionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
    public bool isPlayed { get; set; }






}

 public class SetResult
{
    public int SetResultID { get; set; }
    public int Team1Result { get; set; }
    public int? Team1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public int Team2Result { get; set; }
    public int? Team2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team2 { get; set; }
    public int? MatchID { get; set; }
    public virtual Match Match { get; set; }
    public int SetOrder { get; set; }

}


 public class MatchResultVM
{
    public MatchResultVM()
    {
        SetResults = new List<SetResult>();
    }

    public virtual Match Match { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SetResult> SetResults { get; set; }
}
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult labb([FromForm] MatchResultVM vm)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("labb/5");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like posting a nested model problem to me. Please make sure that the `name` attribute for all the model properties is set using the nested notation using the . operator e.g. `SetResults[0].Team1Result`. This should be handled by `@Html` helper methods automatically. Please check if you are generating HTML for the model correctly like below:

```
@model MatchResultVM

for (var i = 0; i < Model.SetResults.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.SetResults[i].Team1Result)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.SetResults[i].Team2Result)
    ...  
}
```

The above code should generate HTML like below:

```
<input name="SetResults[0].Team1Result" id="SetResults_0__Team1Result" />
<input name="SetResults[0].Team2Result" id="SetResults_0__Team2Result" />
<input name="SetResults[1].Team1Result" id="SetResults_1__Team1Result" />
<input name="SetResults[1].Team2Result" id="SetResults_1__Team2Result" />
...
```

In Asp.Net Core, you can also take advantage of `TagHelpers` instead of `HtmlHelpers`, so you can write the for loop like below using the input TagHelper. For more information regarding TagHelpers please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.SetResults.Count(); i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model.SetResults[i].Team1Result" />
    <input asp-for="@Model.SetResults[i].Team2Result" />
    ...  
}
```

**If you can please post the razor view as well, it would be helpful to see what's going on**

Comment: Its working when i manually enters the inputs.
Problem now is that Model.SetResults.Count() is zero so the for loop is never iterating.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you please post the razor view?